# Htaccess error cannot compile regular expression '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_,()&'/-\\s]+)$'

Tags: php, .htaccess

Compile regular expression server error cannot compile regular expression '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_,()&'/-\s]+)$' but actually my htaccess code is:
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ loader.php?option=home [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)$ loader.php?option=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)$ loader.php?option=$1&sub=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_,()&'/-\s]+)$ loader.php?option=$1&page=$2&storeid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s/]+)$ loader.php?option=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_,/-\s]+)$ loader.php?option=$1&storeid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_,/-\s]+)$ loader.php?option=$1&sub=$2&page=$3storeid=$4 [L]

Comment: It is difficult to see what your actual question is.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and see what the error is.

Comment: `check on remote server`. Not on localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Upto 

RewriteRule ^$ loader.php?option=home [L] is fine but this line stops further reading of the code. While using this htaccess, it shows error on my website, it means my website is totally down.

Comment: server error log says: [Thu Aug 28 21:23:37 2014] [alert] [client 103.235.199.238] /home/paveen/public_html/.htaccess: 
RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\\s]+)$'